# Python Zipfile write - OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error

Tags: python, zipfile

OS Lubuntu 18.04

Пытаюсь записать архив - на середине получаю ошибку:

```
  File "zipping_img.py", line 23, in <module>
  zip_file.write(file)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 1646, in write
  shutil.copyfileobj(src, dest, 1024*8)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/shutil.py", line 79, in copyfileobj
  buf = fsrc.read(length)
  OSError: [Errno 5] Input/output error
```

Код:

```
import os
import zipfile

os.chdir('pictures/img/')

files = list(os.listdir())

zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(f'images.zip', 'w')

for file in files:
    zip_file.write(file)

zip_file.close()
```

Я так понимаю, что дело в размере некоторых файлов?

Comment: Если вдруг возникает ошибка чтения просто так - это может быть признаком того, что у вас умирает диск

Comment: НЕ просто так. Другие папки записывет нормально. Тут тоже: до определенного момента работает нормально, потом выдает ошибку.

Comment: Ну а если просто попытаться вручную скопировать проблемный файл куда-нибудь через обычный Проводник (или какой там в Lubuntu стандартный файловый менеджер) — он копируется без ошибок?

Comment: Вы правы - там были "битые" jpeg файлы, которые не открывались. Если их пропускать, то все нормально работает.